# Simplify the code in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to simplify this code to avoid hardcoding. I mean the variable `baseUrl`

```
<div class="pagination">
        @{
            int pageIndex = ViewBag.PageIndex;
            int pageSize = ViewBag.PageSize;
            int rowsCount = ViewBag.TotalRecords;
            string locale = ViewBag.Locale;
            string baseUrl = pageIndex == 1 ?
                Request.RawUrl + "/page" :
                string.Format("/{0}/tags/{1}/page", locale, Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["tag"]);
        }
        @Html.Pager(baseUrl, pageIndex, pageSize, rowsCount)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have route whitch handles such URLs. So use `@Url.RouteUrl("routename", route_data)` where in route date you will put all necessary values:

```
string baseUrl = Url.RouteUrl("routename", new { tags = locale, page = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["tag"] });
```